# How do I adjust the format of GNOME's digital clock to an advanced custom format?

Tags: gnome, clock, gnome-panel

The digital clock of GNOME I am referring to is indicated in this screenshot:
[image]
(The image shows the date/time as “Sat 12:49 PM”.)

This is the advanced custom format I would like GNOME's digital clock to have:

```
%l:%M:%S %p %A, %e %B %Y
```

At the moment, this format would result in:

```
1:05:10 pm Saturday, 26 December 2015
```

If I would need to install an extra extension to get this custom format, I am willing to.  Please just tell me the name of the extension I would need and how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, I know but I've found a way to do it. (This does, however, require an extension - with modification - to work.)

[image: Demonstration of updated DateTime format]

Here's the step-by-step guide:

1. Install the "Change clock format" extension (by `silvioricardoc`) https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/617/fixclock/
2. Change to the following directory: `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/FixClock@silvioricardoc/`
3. Open the file, `extension.js`, with your favourite editor.
4. At the top of the file, you should find a definition for a variable called `panelClockFormat`
5. You can change this to your desired format (as you can see from my format, you can also use JavaScript in your format too.)
6. Save the file, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, simply enter `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**NOTE:** If the extension directory doesn't work, you may have to try this one: `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/FixClock@silvioricardoc/extension.js`